# How to implement BIND and MSDNS in one Domain

Tags: linux, windows, domain-name-system, bind

We are about to setup a new web platform with a mix of Linux servers and MS servers, we are planning to utilise MSDNS for our AD domain and MS servers and will use Bind for our root nameservers for our website (lets say www.example.com) in addition to being a location for storing our Linux server records, my question is;

1.What should our AD Domain be?

2.What should our Bind Domain be?

Can we have the following

1. AD = www.example.com , BIND = www.example.com
2. AD = windows.example.com , BIND = www.example.com
3. AD = www.example.net , BIND = www.example.com

The Bind (root) servers will always be www.example.com, so i guess the question is, what do we do with our Windows domain?! .. We initially thought to have it the same as the BIND domain (www.example.com) and use forwarders in MSDNS to the root servers for lookup of our Linux servers, but can these co-exist and can BIND look to the MSDNS for the Windows Server records.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks,

**Edit:**

Apologies for not making this clear as to what will be internal and external DNS, however we have done some more work on this... We will be looking to running Bind for our external domain DNS, www.example.com .

Then we will be runnning internal Bind DNS for our linux host records and internal MSDNS for our windows host records on www.example.local for example... Would this be possible, or would there be any headaches around this?

Comment: Can you clarify what needs to be internet visible, and what is going to be internal only?  (servers as well as host records)  It sounds like you're thinking of using just bind for external DNS, but both systems in tandem for resolution of internal hosts, which is probably a lot more complicated than it needs to be - a subdomain would be on the right track, but why not just have all the internal host records in one place?

Answer (score 0):

As per my answer to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/233698/sbs-domain-name-choice), I'd personally go with example.local internally on your AD DNS and example.com on your BIND DNS for external records.

Obviously, configure your AD DNS forwarders to point to your BIND server.